# Hosting a WCF Service Application on IIS 7 where I already have a WebSite

Tags: wcf, iis-7

Can somebody help me.

I just developed a WCF Service Application on my pc, and everything works fine when I run it on localhost!

But now I want to host this project on my IIS7 where I already have a website.  I would Like to host my WCF in this website, because I would like to use the same hostname and IP Address,  is this possible ?? I dont know if I can Add a Application in the website or something like that.

If this is possible how can I do this???

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can host your application in your IIS website, even if it has a website installed on it. You need to create a new application in that website.

First of all, you need to make sure your service has a `.svc` file that points to the location of the service, copy the contents of your `App.Config` (Service config file) to a new `web.config` (in the same physical directory as your App.config) and also remove the `<host><baseAddresses>` section in the newly created `web.config`, point the physical path of the application to the location of this service on your computer. Once that's taken care of, just be sure to edit the default website bindings to enable the specific bindings your service uses, for example if your service has `netTcpBinding` then go to: Website -> 'Edit Bindings...' -> 'Add...' then choose the applicable protocol and assign it the ports. Then on your application go to 'Advanced Settings' and enable the respective protocol, for example your `netTcpBinding` service will typically have `http,net.tcp` as it's enabled protocols.  and you're set. If you run into teething errors make sure the default app pool (or which ever application pool your website is using) has the required permissions to access and read the physical directory on your computer in which the service resides.

Comment: Ok Thanks !! I didnt see you answer before.... sorry ... I did something like this haha but thanks  it is a very good answer !!